# Cartoon with boys on holiday in a fishing village find a pearl-activated portal to another dimension

Tags: story-identification, animation

I am struggling to find a movie that my brother and I watched about 10 years ago (mid-2000s)

Two boys had their holidays in a fishing village. They found a strange pearl in a toy shop that opened a portal to another freaky dimension where a silent girl rode a GIANT white thing (it might've been a dog). The girl was naked but her body had bird-like white feathers all over it except for the head. Another thing I remember is that it had two timelines in it. In the second one they were grown-ups in a restaurant discussing whether it was real or not. I don't remember why, but they somehow damaged the pearl and caused some problems in that pocket dimension.

I watched this in Russia on a VHS cassette. It looked like anime but it might have been from a European studio.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: i just dont know how it is called in english

Comment: Heavy Metal? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kGcoijHMzY

Comment: no i dont think so

Answer (score 4):

I actually found it (I realized that the girl's name was Mari or something like that). It was *[Mari Iyagi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/2133/Mari_Iyagi)*.

[image: Mari Iyagi]

> When office worker Nam-woo receives a package from childhood friend Jun-ho it transports him back to their last summer together. Back to their hometown in a small fishing village it the last few days before Jun-ho left for boarding school in Seoul. When a marble and an abandoned lighthouse had the power to transport him to a fantastic world where a mysterious flying girl named Mari lived.

**Trailer**

Comment: Please explain why it matches. You can accept your own answer 48 hours after you asked the question.